# How to add 3rd party dependencies into a play framework project

Tags: java, playframework, sbt

I'm trying to write my first play application. 
I took the started project on playframework website, and started from there.
For some cases I need to import 3rd party libraries (apache and so).
I've tries to add maven to my project, however I don't find the right way to make my classes aware of the jars that maven fetched.
In the play's website they recommend using play maven:update, however the play command was replaced with sbt, which seems to lack this option.
Maybe I'm missing something, but I'm currently clueless.
Thanks

Comment: If you're just getting started, it might be easiest to base your project on some example, like this one: https://github.com/playframework/play-java-starter-example `sbt run` will automatically fetch all dependencies (however you'll have to put them into `build.sbt` rather than `pom.xml`).

Comment: Thank you! problem solved when I updated the build.sbt !!!